# c# method to a nodeJs

Tags: c#, node.js

i have an function in c# and i need to convert it to NodeJs and i faced some issuse

this is my c# method

```
  private uint[] data = null;
  public int dataLength;

 public Matrix(long value)
    { 
        data = new uint[70];
        long num = value;
        dataLength = 0;
        while (value != 0L && dataLength < 70)
        {
            data[dataLength] = (uint)(value & uint.MaxValue);
            value >>= 32;
            dataLength++;
             
        }
         
        if (num > 0)
        {
            if (value != 0L || (data[69] & 2147483648u) != 0)
            {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Positive overflow in constructor.");
            }
        }
        else if (num < 0 && (value != -1 || ((int)data[dataLength - 1] & int.MinValue) == 0))
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Negative underflow in constructor.");
        }
        if (dataLength == 0)
        {
            dataLength = 1;
        }
    }
```

my NodeJs method i write it depend on the c# one

```
this.data = null;
this.dataLength;

    Matrix(value)
        {  
            this.data = Buffer.alloc(70);
            var num = value;
            this.dataLength = 0;
            while (value != 0 && this.dataLength < 70)
            {
                this.data[this.dataLength] =  (value & 4294967295); //uint.MaxValue
                value >>= 32;
                this.dataLength++; 
            } 
            if (num > 0)
            { 
                if (value != 0 || (this.data[69] & 2147483648) != 0)
                {
                     throw new Error("Positive overflow in constructor.");
                }
            }
            else if (num < 0 && (value != -1 || (this.data[dataLength - 1] & -2147483648) == 0)) //int.MinValue
            {
                 throw new Error("Negative underflow in constructor.");
            }
            if (this.dataLength == 0)
            {
                this.dataLength = 1;
            }
        }
```

lets say the value its 22

now there is no error in code but there is different value in

value >>= 32;

when the `value` of type `int`  and use rightShift it give same result like nodeJs
but if the `value` of type `long` with same value `22` its give different result

as i know there is no `Long` `ulong` in NodeJs so did its possible to convert this method ?
and why `rightshift` a value with different type give different result as i mentioned value 22 >>= 32 of type int give different result of value 22 >>= 32 of type long

Comment: A long in C# is probable 64-bits, the variable you are using has [2^53-1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: "and why rightshift a value with different type give different result as i mentioned value 22 >>= 32 of type int give different result of value 22 >>= 32 of type long". This might help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#shift-count-of-the-shift-operators

Comment: @E.Shcherbo thank you i understand now why there is different 
but did there is any solution for Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS the maximum integer value is 2^53-1 so that's why you cannot work with them with the same precision as in C# `long` (64-bit signed integer).

You can try to use `BigInt` to make your code compatible with C#. Bear in mind not to convert explicitly or implicitly to `Number` type while working with `BigInt`.

Comment: did you mean this moudle ?
https://github.com/substack/node-bigint

Comment: I mean BigInt type - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Node.js supports BigInt since version 10.4

Comment: Thank you. Bear in mind not to convert explicitly or implicitly to Number type while working with BigInt / did you mean finish all Bitwise operation and after that change to Number?

Comment: only if are sure you'll get a correct Number after all operations.

Comment: did i will face any issuse if I change to BigInt and make some Bitwise operation
and back to Number and make some operation and Back to BigInt and made some 
Bitwise operation like this

Comment: There is no guarantee that BigInt number is still be suitable for Number without losing accuracy after Bitwise operations. If after Bitwise operations you'll get a number that is greater then a maximum number for Number-type then you lose accuracy or even you can get a random number at all.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer and comment it's definitely helpful